# Ext.ux.grid.GridSummary() is not a constructor

Tags: extjs

I found several examples how to use Ext.ux.grid.GridSummary() in GridPanel, main problem here is if I try to summary plugin on this way:

```
plugins: new Ext.ux.grid.GridSummary(),
```

I get JS error that Ext.ux.grid.GridSummary() is not a constructor?!

Any idea about this or hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you include the correct JavaScript file? The `ux`-namespace is not part of the standard ExtJS distribution and must be included manually. You must include

```
<!-- base library --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<!-- extensions --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/GroupSummary.css" />
...
<!-- ExtJS library: base/adapter --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script> 
<!-- ExtJS library: all widgets --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/ext-all.js"></script> 
<!-- extensions --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/GroupSummary.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

Just noticed: shouldn't it be **`Ext.ux.grid.GroupSummary`**?

Comment: Please show some code - especially your includes and the relevant part where the above code is used.

Comment: @Stefan is correct, this error generally occurs when you have misspelt the module name

Comment: you are corect should be GroupSummary() dunno where I found a GridSummary()...:( thanks for help!

Comment: @vaske: If it's working now, you should accept this answer to show others how your problem could be solved.